# Configuring MyBatis with Spring MVC for multiple datasources

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis, multi-database

I have been trying to configure MyBatis with Spring MVC to work with multiple databases. I  have a page which is trying to connect to one of the DB's to fetch data, so that it can be populated into the drop-down boxes.

Now I am not sure what is wrong with this configuration, but I am receiving the following error:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException. org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

I am providing the XML file here for your reference

```
<bean id="dataSource1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.2.5:1529:DITOS" />
        <property name="username" value="return" />
        <property name="password" value="return" />
    </bean>

    <!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage"
            value="p.com.ent.appl.return.dev.dao,p.com.ent.appl.return.dep.dao,p.com.ent.appl.return.dao.otheruser" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory1" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="cashReturnTx"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed 
        when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory1" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/mybatis/sqlmap-config.xml" />
        <!-- <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:/com/vrn/ent/dev/daoxml/*.xml" 
            /> -->
        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath*:/p/com/ent/appl/return/**/daoxml/*.xml" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sqlSession1" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@4.24.80.15:1522:LM" />
        <property name="username" value="RETURN" />
        <property name="password" value="OWNER" />
    </bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage"
            value="p.com.ent.appl.return.dev.dao,p.com.ent.appl.return.dep.dao,p.com.ent.appl.return.dao.otheruser" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="otherUserTx"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed 
        when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/mybatis/sqlmap-config.xml" />
        <!-- <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:/com/vrn/ent/dev/daoxml/*.xml" 
            /> -->
        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath*:/p/com/ent/appl/return/**/daoxml/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: We have solved it. The actual problem was the property name="mapperLocations". Here we have given the same location. But we changed the location and made it different for both datasources it has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception: `BadSqlGrammarException: ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name`, a DB is hit.

Read about error **ORA-06576**.

Issue is likeky be related to how the procedure is called. Right way is `{ CALL MyProcedure (#arg0, #arg1) }`

Configuration shows that same mappers may be used with both datasources, what happens then if target schemas are different?